# Cannot get backbone view to render

Tags: javascript, html, backbone.js, backbone-views, backbone.js-collections

I looping through a collection in an attempt to add a row to a table on every loop. Here is the code that loops the collection, and build the single view,

```
App.Views.OrganisationMembersTab = Backbone.View.extend({

el: '#members',

template: _.template( $('#tpl-members-tab-panel').html() ),

events: {

},

initialize: function() {
    this.$el.html( this.template() );
    this.render();
},

render: function() {
    this.addAll();
},

addAll: function() {
    this.collection.each( this.addOne, this);
},

addOne: function(model) {
    console.log(model);
    var tableRow = new App.Views.OrganisationsMemberRow({
        model: model
    });
    tableRow.render();
}
```

});

The single view that gets called to build the row looks like this,

```
App.Views.OrganisationsMemberRow = Backbone.View.extend({

    el: '.members-list tbody',

    template: _.template($('#tpl-organisation-member-row').html() ),

    events: {

    },

    initialize: function() {

    },

    render: function() {

        this.$el.prepend( this.template({
            member: this.model.toJSON()
        }));

        return this;
    }

});
```

The model that is being used once it has been parsed to JSON using `toJSON()` looks like this,

```
email: "john.doe@email.com"  
first_name: "John"  
last_name: "Doe"
```

The template for the row looks like this,

```
<script type="text/template" id="tpl-members-tab-panel">

    <table class="table table-striped members-list">

        <thead> 

            <tr>
                <th>A</th>
                <th>B</th>
                <th>C</th>
                <th>D</th>
            </tr>

        </thead>

        <tbody>
            <tr>
                <td colspan="4"><button class="btn btn-success btn-sm pull-right">Add &plus;</button></td>
            </tr>
        </tbody>

    </table>

</script>
```

The above builds the main table components, and the next template is actually for a data row.

```
<script type="text/template" id="tpl-organisation-member-row">
    <tr>
        <td>#</td>  
        <td><%= first_name %> <%= last_name %></td>
        <td>Admin <input type="checkbox" /></td>
        <td>Remove</td>
    </tr>

</script>
```

All I get output the the main table and then in the main tbody I get either nothing prepended or an empty `<tr>` why is this?

Answer (score 0):

Your current implementation is a little confused. Your row view has no `tagName` so by default you'll be appending `div`s to your `tbody`.

The first thing I'd do is take the `<tr>` tag out of your `tpl-organisation-member-row` template and then alter your row view like so:

```
App.Views.OrganisationsMemberRow = Backbone.View.extend({

    tagName: 'tr',

    template: _.template($('#tpl-organisation-member-row').html() ),

    render: function() {
       this.$el.html(this.template(this.model.toJSON()));
       return this;
    }
});
```

Member row template:

```
<script type="text/template" id="tpl-organisation-member-row">
        <td>#</td>  
        <td><%= first_name %> <%= last_name %></td>
        <td>Admin <input type="checkbox" /></td>
        <td>Remove</td>
</script>
```

Then I'd prefer to control appending the rows from your `App.Views.OrganisationMembersTab` view. So in your `addOne` method do the following:

```
addOne: function(){
    var tableRow = new App.Views.OrganisationsMemberRow({
        model: model
    });
    this.$('tbody').append(tableRow.render().el);
}
```

Comment: tagName is not required, all the DOM I need in the template, and I can append that `this.$el` as it is already within the DOM. Maybe I understand that wrong?

Comment: @Udders You're right, tagName is not required but if you don't supply it it will be a `div` by default - meaning you'll have `divs` as the first children of `tbody` - where `tr`s are expected. What you'll end up with is something like `<tbody><div><tr>... .... ...</tr></div></tbody>`. You don't want this, hence removing the `tr` from the template and adding the `tagName` to the view

Comment: Wait, you are confusing me a little, I thought if you declare tagname and classname etc, and not el then those attributes would be el, and if you delcare el then would take precedent over tagname?

Comment: @Udders Yes, I believe you're correct, but in my changes above I have taken out `el` from your row view. In my opinion, you're much better off controlling where your member rows get rendered from your `App.Views.OrganisationMembersTab`, using `this.$('tbody').append(tableRow.render().el);`

Answer (score 0):

The problem is with your template which doesn't use `member` property, just use whole model instead.

You need replace

```
    this.$el.prepend( this.template({
        member: this.model.toJSON()
    }));
```

with

```
    this.$el.prepend( this.template(
        this.model.toJSON()
    ));
```

[working example](http://jsbin.com/misuvejeza/2/edit)